# Select row count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 'table_1' as FlowStepCount, COUNT(fs.ID)  
FROM [FlowSteps] fs
where fs.FlowID = 120
UNION all
SELECT 'table_2' as FlowStepAssignmentCount, COUNT(fsa.ID)  
FROM [FlowStepAssignments] fsa
where fsa.FlowStepID IN (select ID from [FlowSteps] where FlowID = 120)
```

I want to show query like this:

```
FlowStepCount   FlowStepAssignmentCount
18              64
```

I want also join ID of FLOW table with FLOWSTEP table's FlowID. I tried to join 3 table but couldnt solve it.

I actually want to write query like this:

```
SELECT 
   count(fs.ID) as FlowStepCount, 
   count(fsa.ID) as FlowStepAssignmentCount
FROM
   [Flow] f, 
   [FlowSteps] fs,
   [FlowStepAssignments] fsa
WHERE      
   fs.ID = fsa.FlowStepID AND
   f.ID = fs.FlowID AND
   f.ID = 120
```

Any suggestions? How can I join 3 tables and getting count(*) of them just giving FlowID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem:

```
SELECT count(distinct fs.ID) as FlowStepCount, 
       count(distinct fsa.ID) as FlowStepAssignmentCount
FROM [Flow] f left join 
     [FlowSteps] fs
     on f.ID = fs.FlowID left join
     [FlowStepAssignments] fsa
     on fs.ID = fsa.FlowStepID
WHERE f.ID = 120;
```

The more efficient way would generally be to use subqueries:

```
select (select count(*) from FlowSteps fs where f.ID = fs.FlowID) as FlowStepCount,
       (select count(*) from FlowStepAssignments fsa where f.ID = fsa.FlowID) as FlowStepAssignmentCount,

from Flow f
where f.id = 120;
```

Comment: the first query you wrote is so close to my solution but it doesnt count the Flowsteps that are not exists in Flowstepassignment table. It only gives count of which has relation.

Comment: @cihata87 . . . That is because I used inner joins, as you had in the example in the question (which used implicit join syntax).  Just replace `join` with `left join` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but left join, left outer join or right join doesn't change the result

Comment: You forgot to add the `fs` reference after `left join [FlowSteps]` :) BTW...it's supposed to work... See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63607/7